# Workflow for tracking an upstream repository in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, workflow

I'm not sure what's the best Mercurial workflow for what I'm trying to accomplish, so I'm looking for any tips and ideas.

Main development happens on a master repo, and I have many customer specific repos that are nearly identical to the master, with few tweaks here and there specific to the needs of that customer.

My current workflow is to have a named branch in the master repo (name: *webapp*), then clone that repo for each customer. Each customer repo has a named branch (name: *customer#*), and then I periodically pull from master repo, merging the two branches (*webapp* and *customer#*) and tidying up conflicts.

Is this the best workflow for what I'm trying to do, or is there a better way to track an upstream repo with small tweaks added for every clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the textbook case where feature branching (which is what you're effectively doing) is a bad choice. Rather, consider [branching by abstraction](http://www.slideshare.net/cb372/branching-strategies), which is *not* branching in DVCS sense, but rather branching in code.

Comment: Exactly. I've learned this the hard way: merge times for the client specific repos kept increasing as they have diverged over the last year....

Comment: Thanks Anton for the presentation, that's something I've trying to do for a while, didn't know it had a name! I've moved most of the features in runtime flags and the database, the rest remains in separate named branches. It shouldn't be too difficult to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Not "better"|"worse", but slightly different way may be using MQ (and single mainline without branches) and mq-patches for customer-specific changes instead of branches in different repos.

In extremal case it can be single repository with core in permanent changesets and set if MQ-queues (queue per customer) and pull|merge|resolve will be replaced with pull|apply path|resolve|save edited patch

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there is no simpler or easier ways than your current approach.

The real difficulty is *not* a problem of branching/workflow strategy, but a problem of your overall code structure: I mean you have potential conflicts between the main and the custom branches (or versions). This problem won't go away automatically by choosing a "better" branching/workflow strategy. Because it's essentially a problem of code, you have to tackle it at the *code* level, either by resolving the conflicts manually during the process of merging the main to the custom branch, or by insulating the  various customizations from the main code so that any change in the latter won't affect the former. Either way obviously has its pros and cons. If mergings and conflicts happen very frequently, you would like to consider to adopt the second way; otherwise, your current approach is just fine IMO.